# python : error encoding 'ascii' ONLY running with crontab

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, cron, ascii

My python script *working very well when i'm running it in console mode*. It's write a html file, convert with pdfkit in pdf and send a mail. All is allright.

But, **when this script running from the crontab, there's some encoding error**.

```
if len(html) > 0:
    with open(file_html_to_pdf, 'w') as file:
        message  = '[PDF] >> writing the html file "{0}"'.format(file_html_to_pdf)
        logging.info(message)
        print(message)
        file.write(html)
else:
    raise IOError('html file is invalid !')
```

In the crontab, I've done this :

```
# VARIABLES FOR PYTHON
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8


*/5 * * * * /home/users/my-user/my-project/env/bin/python /home/users/my-user/my-project/cronjob.py > /var/log/apps/my-project/cron_error_my-project.log 2>&1
```

And in the bashrc :

```
# set locale utf-8 in french.....et voilà
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
export LC_ALL=fr_FR.utf-8
export LANG="$LC_ALL"
```

The error message :

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf4' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)
...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 400: ordinal not in range(128)
...
Message: ('<!> Error  => ', UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<head>\n  <title>---
```

Python version :

```
$ /home/users/my-user/my-project/env/bin/python --version
Python 3.4.2
```

I don't understand why :(. Can anybody help me?

Thanks

F.

Comment: Not sure if this will work but could you try: `*/5 * * * * source /home/users/my-user/.bashrc; /home/users/my-user/my-project/env/bin/python /home/users/my-user/my-project/cronjob.py > /var/log/apps/my-project/cron_error_my-project.log 2>&1` to run all commands in .bashrc before run your python program.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but sorry, it's not working, same errors...

Comment: You can bypass the default encoding by wrapping the binary STDOUT buffer in a properly encoded `TextIOWrapper`, like so: `stdout_enc = open(sys.stdout.buffer, encoding='utf8')`. Then pass this as the `file=` parameter to print, or simply assign it to `sys.stdout`.

Comment: Thanks for help. But if I restart the session, the service cron, and add "DISPLAY=:0"  before the python file, it's working. Sincerely, I don't now why :(